# mod_wsgi + Apache 2 -- not able to access wsgi file

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I have installed libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 from the synaptic package manager ( Ubuntu 11.04) and because I had used package manager, it automatically kept the wsgi.load and wsgi.conf files at the right places with the symbolic links.  I created a wsgi script in the /var/www folder,but,I keep getting a "You don't have permission to access /name.wsgi on this server' . I am the superuser .   What could have gone wrong for this to happen ?

My goal : My goal is to call a python script ,  passing a latitude longitude as parameters and then getting the result.  I saw mod_wsgi somewhere and that is why I have installed it. If there is an easier way to call a script from the url itself ( http://localhost.com/test.py?lat=10 & long=20) , then, I would be happy to know that ( Very happy infact).

Answer (score 0):

For a start, go watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

It will explain basics of setting up mod_wsgi and describe problems you may encounter with file system permissions.

Then also go read the mod_wsgi documentation, starting with:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I haven't seen the first link , will do. But, I have seen the second one. Infact, initially, I had installed mod_wsgi from source itself and then done the wsgi.load and wsgi.conf part manually ( and tested sudo aen2mod ) , but , I suffered the same problem there too. I will post the snapshots in the mailing list ( Observed the instruction to post doubts in mailing lists *after* I had already posted here)

Comment: It is impossible to know what your issue is because you haven't actually supplied the parts of your Apache configuration which say how you have mounted your WSGI application. So, update your question with that and we will not have to guess what it looks like.